# Nginx SSL request process

Tags: nginx, ssl-certificate, http, curl

I have a Nginx 1.10 with this 2 sites:

site A:

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/example.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/example.com/privkey.pem;    
        server_name example.com;
        return  301  https://www.$host$request_uri;
}
```

site B:

```
server {
        listen 443 default_server ssl;
        listen [::]:443 default_server ssl;
        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/default/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/default/privkey.pem;    
        server_name _;
        return  301  https://qqq.$host$request_uri;
}
```

The server IP is 10.10.10.10

Why when I execute: `curl -Iv --header "Host: example.com" https://10.10.10.10. -k`

It gives me the *default* certificate, not the *example.com*.

But if I execute  `curl -Iv --resolve example.com:443:10.10.10.10 https://example.com -k` it loads the proper certificate.

So nginx do not use the *Host* header to choose the SSL certificate 
What parameter uses nginx to decide which certificate to load?

Any reference would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: How could a web server choose a certificate based on a header he has yet to decipher?  That's what SNI is for.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12941703/use-curl-with-sni-server-name-indication#12942331  says that if yout version of curl is recent enough, "curl https: //example.com" should do the trick (ie. use SNI).